# Unable to write to json file using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to execute a query and write the results to my `title.json` file.

The query is located in my `lib/conn.php` page, when I visit this page in my browser I can see `connected`, and when I look at NetBeans I can see that the file `title.json` has been created as it should be, however it's empty.

I am able to delete and re-create this file by visiting the `lib/conn.php` page, therefore there must be something wrong with my code/array?

My current code is as follows;

```
<?php

// Create connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'MyDbUser', 'MyDbPass', 'MyDbName');

// Check connection
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
    else{
        echo "connected </br>";
    }

$sql = ("SELECT title FROM publication");

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row['title'];
}

//file_put_contents('../test.txt','Hello World. Test!'); // this works

//var_dump($data); // this works

file_put_contents('../title.json', json_encode($data));

?>
```

For testing purposes I have tried `var_dump($data)` which does print the array on screen in the following format;

```
array(592) { [0]=> string(206) "Some text..." [1]=> string(183) "Some text..." [2]=> string(139) "Some text..." [3]=> string(227) "Some text...
```

I have also run the query locally in phpmyadmin and it does return a list of titles as expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does `is_writeable("../title.json");` returh?

Comment: What happens if you echo the `json_encode($data)` value? Do you have error reporting on? Is the json extension turned on?

Comment: Could you try with: `$data[] = mb_detect_encoding($row['title'], 'UTF-8', true);` too, check if any value is false instead of true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82471/discussion-between-johnny-s-and-jite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPs `json_encode` docs says:

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

If a string is not `UTF-8`, `json_encode` will return an empty string (one could wish that it threw an exception or produced an error/warning with some... useful information instead, but well... `php`... hehe).
What you could try, is to encode all the strings to UTF-8 (double check so that the strings looks correct after encoding).
This is easiest done by using the `utf8_encode` function when you add them to the array:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $data[] = utf8_encode($row['title']);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks @Jite - explanation really helps, as does your troubleshooting!